# Clarification of ASP.NET MVC routing and model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, model-binding

In ASP.NET MVC, I have recently found out that:

This doesn't work and results in an HTTP 404.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TestModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

This works fine.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(TestModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

This also works fine:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult GetIndex(TestModel model)
    {
        return View("Index", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult PostIndex(TestModel model)
    {
        return View("Index", model);
    }
}
```

I would like an explanation of why the first version doesn't work, but the other two do work. I would also appreciate if someone could tell me how I can modify the first version to make it work. I like the first version because it is more concise (1 method rather than 2) and also filters out unnecessary HTTP methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GET and POST to same Controller Action in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232013/get-and-post-to-same-controller-action-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: It does seem to be the same issue, though worded differently. I also asked for the reason why the obvious option doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP verb attributes are mutually exclusive, a request cannot be both GET and POST at the same time. Instead, you have to do this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(TestModel model) { ... }
```

Comment: It's not letting me accept your answer yet. I'll mark it as accepted in about 5 more minutes :) Thanks!