# Redirect from POST action to POST action

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have 2 POST actions, each one wants to redirect from one to another:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Foo()
{
    bool isBar = handleFoo();
    if (isBar) return RedirectToAction("Bar");
    else return View();
}


[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Bar()
{
    bool isFoo = handleBar();
    if (isFoo) return RedirectToAction("Foo");
    else return View();
}
```

Assumedly, the user submits a form and runs the `Bar` method, if a boolean expression `isFoo` is true, then return the `Foo` method with its view, else return the current `Bar` view.

Currently, my code cannot return the correct View for the action, how can I do it?

Comment: `RedirectToAction` is a GET, not a POST

Comment: make foo as httpGet

Comment: @Saurabh Both of them are POST methods.

Comment: @MiP if you cant change it to httpGet than remove it and use [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post | HttpVerbs.Get)] , need more detail of your logic why you want post method to post method redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please specify the View name also in your case:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Foo()
{
    bool isBar = handleFoo();
    if (isBar) return Bar();
    else return View("Foo");
}


[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Bar()
{
    bool isFoo = handleBar();
    if (isFoo) return Foo();
    else return View("Bar");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RedirectToAction is using GEt not POST, so I would assume that the both actions in same controller so you can call the other action as calling a method like this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Foo()
{
    bool isBar = handleFoo();
    if (isBar) return Bar();
    else return View();
}


[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Bar()
{
    bool isFoo = handleBar();
    if (isFoo) return Foo();
    else return View();
}
```

Comment: This is what I did, but it returned the wrong View, i.e. `Foo()` returns `Bar()`, but still gets Foo's view.

Comment: what are handleFoo and HandleBar methods?

Comment: it doesn't matter in the current example, you can think that it returns `Random.NextDouble() > 0.5`.

Comment: have you debug it?

Comment: Mip is correct Foo will always return its own view only.

Answer (score 0):

Hope i got a solution for your problem , and the code should look like this.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Foo()
{
    bool isBar = handleFoo();
    if (isBar) return RedirectToAction("Bar");
    else return View();
}


[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Bar()
{
    bool isFoo = handleBar();
    if (isFoo) return RedirectToAction("Foo");
    else return View();
}
```

Note : Kindly make the action attribute for **foo() method as [HttpGet].**

Because RedirectToAction() supports only  the get request, ie.it is like give a new request from the browser.

And for the Bar() method you can retain actionattribute as [httppost] , since it is calling from the form.

Hope the above information will be useful to solve your problem, kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: Both of them are POST methods.

Comment: Then Try the below link and see whether it works :https://stackoverflow.com/a/3740110/3397630

Comment: This could work, but I'm afraid ASP.NET would choose `GET` and I don't want to expose urgly queries in the URL, not what I'm looking for at the momment. btw the correct attribute in .NET Core should be `[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]`

Comment: [HttpPost] is shorthand for [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]. The only difference is that you can't use [HttpGet, HttpPost] (and similar) together on the same action. If you want an action to respond to both GETs and POSTs, you must use [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]

Source/Taken From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16034262/3397630

Hope it was helpful ,thanks

Comment: I think `HttpVerbs` haven't been supported in .NET Core 1.1 yet so we have to use string array. The point is I can't make my method accept `GET`, so no `[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]`.